# can any one help me with this trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, triggers

I am new to databases. So, trying my best to design a inventory management system. I would like to do the following

Database name is "yh_electronic"

Table Name is - **orders**

attributes are:-

Order_Total DECIMAL (15,2)
Total_Paid DECIMAL (15,2)
Balance_Due DECIMAL (15,2)

I would like to have a Balance_Due column auto filled when order_Total and Total_Paid columns are inserted with new values or when Total_paid value is updated. So, I have tried to create a trigger with the below query:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS yh_electronics.orders_AINS$$ 

USE `yh_electronics`$$ 


CREATE TRIGGER `orders_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW 

UPDATE Balance_Due SET NEW.Balance_Due=NEW.Order_Total-NEW.Total_paid$$ 

DELIMITER ;
```

The query is executed well.

But when I insert a new row with values for Order_Total and Total_Paid i am seeing 
error code:1442. cannt update table 'order' in stored function/trigger becuase its is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

can any one please help me out with this if trigger is not possible to create , then some one help me how to create a procedure for this. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to be called BEFORE

```
CREATE TRIGGER `orders_AINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `orders` FOR EACH ROW
```